# Issue with grep, egrep in solaris

Tags: grep, solaris

I have an issue when I execute this command in Solaris:

```
grep -Ev "(^#|^EBM_SERVER|^$)" ${EBM_CONF} | awk -F, '{print $2"|"}' | tr -d "\n" | sed 's/|$//g'
```

I got this error message:

```
egrep:illegal option -- E
usage: egrep [-bchilnsv] [-e exp] [-f file] [string] [file] ...
egrep:syntax error
```

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris, in the default environment, you get antiquated utilities.

To get more modern utilities, you need to update `$PATH`:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH`:$PATH export PATH
```

That will get you utilities from the 90s as opposed to from the 80s (that's hardly an exaggeration...).

Then your `grep` will behave more like a standard `grep`.

Alternatively, you could use `egrep` instead of `grep -E`.

But here, `awk` being a superset of `egrep`, you don't need `egrep` at all.

```
< "$EBM_CONF" awk -F, '! /^#|^EBM_SERVER|^$/ {print $2"|"}' |
   tr -d "\n" |
   sed 's/|$//g'
```

To join lines with `|`, you'd better use `paste`. Your last two commands can be replaced with `paste -s -d '|' -`. Or you could do the whole thing in `awk`:

```
< "$EBM_CONF" awk -F, '! /^#|^EBM_SERVER|^$/ {printf "%s", sep $2; sep = "|"}'
```